# Node Js/React Js Application Gracefully shutting down

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build, graceful-shutdown

for the first time we deployed the react Build file into the server. in our local server there is no issue.But after deploying into Production server Application is getting shutting down.Can any one please help me, what is the isue and how to prevent it.

this is the Error reference (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dupp.png)